# Looking for a script that can be ran in Chrome to automatically reset the browser settings.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

What I'm looking to do is create a script that we could place on people's desktop to reset some settings back to where I want them for internal web application?

The script will need to reset everytime a user opens and closes the browser.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge says, you cannot just edit settings of a browser without attaining user's permissions. So, it will be better to write a chrome plug-in application and ask you web application users to install that first.

You can identify the plug-in status in your web application.